# Constraining the argument of a constraint

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a first typeclass which accepts lists of lists of lists of … of `leaf`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
class ListTree leaf t where
  lmap :: (leaf -> leaf) -> t -> t
instance ListTree leaf leaf where lmap f v = f v
instance ListTree leaf t => ListTree leaf [t] where lmap f v = map (lmap f) v
```

I have a second typeclass which accepts 2-tuples and 3-tuples of `a`:

```
class Tups a t where
  tmap :: (a -> a) -> t -> t
instance Tups a (a,a) where tmap f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
instance Tups a (a,a,a) where tmap f (x,y,z) = (f x, f y, f z)
```

I would like to combine them to describe nested lists ending with 2- or 3-tuples of some `leaf` type:

```
class LTTree leaf t where
  ltmap :: (a -> a) -> t -> t
instance (Tups leaf x, ListTree x t) => LTTree leaf t where ltmap f v = lmap (tmap f) v
```

However, this last piece of code gives me several errors:

```
Could not deduce (LTTree leaf0 t)
  from the context: LTTree leaf t

In the ambiguity check for ‘ltmap’
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes

Could not deduce (Tups leaf x0)
  from the context: (Tups leaf x, ListTree x t)

In the ambiguity check for an instance declaration
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  In the instance declaration for ‘LTTree leaf t’
```

If I add `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, I still get similar errors.

I can define the `LTTree` class just fine by inlining the code of the other two typeclasses, though:

```
class LTTree leaf t where
  ltmap :: (leaf -> leaf) -> t -> t
instance LTTree leaf (leaf,leaf) where ltmap f (x,y) = (f x, f y)
instance LTTree leaf (leaf,leaf,leaf) where ltmap f (x,y,z) = (f x, f y, f z)
instance LTTree leaf t => LTTree leaf [t] where ltmap f v = map (ltmap f)
```

**How can I combine the `ListTree leaf t` class with the `Tups a t` class so that the leaves of the tree of lists are 2- or 3-tuples of `a`?** I don't mind adding extra GHC extensions if that can help.

If it matters, my real use case is to model trees of lists where the leaves are row-polymorphic record (using CTRex), where each field in the record is an instance of some typeclass (e.g. `Show`, to print the trees).

Comment: I think you'll get more mileage out of using a more direct representation of nested lists: `data Nested a = Flat a | Nested (Nested [a])`

Comment: A few questions. Doesn't `t` determine `leaf` in `LTTree`? Doesn't `t` determine `a` in `Tups`? I think your classes need either fundeps or type families to express these dependencies. I'm not even sure you actually need the classes, though: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This strategy of representing data with typeclasses doesn't really give you anything and getting the encoding right is clearly non-trivial. As other commenters have noted, why not represent your data ... as data? You can represent existentially quantified records with e.g. `data ConstrainedRec c where CRec :: Forall r c => Rec r -> ConstrainedRec c` (where `Rec` and `Forall` are provided by CTrex).

Comment: You're all right, the `data` approach is likely simpler and would work just as well. I'm new to Haskell so I'm not always sure what's the right tool for the job. It was interesting though to learn how to do the encoding as typeclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another issue. Your `ListTree` class is useless!

```
> lmap id [5 :: Integer]
error: blah blah
> lmap id (5 :: Integer)
error: blah blah
> lmap (+2) [[5::Integer], [], [2,3]]
error: blah blah
```

Add some dark magic to fix this first:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, GADTs #-}
class ListTree leaf tree where lmap :: (leaf -> leaf) -> (tree -> tree)
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (leaf ~ tree) => ListTree leaf tree where -- 1
  lmap = id
instance ListTree leaf tree => ListTree leaf [tree] where -- 2
  lmap = map . lmap
```

(`(a ~ b)` is an *equality constraint*; it holds when `a` and `b` are the same type. It needs `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies` to be used.)

According to [the rules of instance resolution](https://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.1/glasgow_exts.html#overlapping-instances), when checking `lmap id [5 :: Integer]`, GHC will come across both instances and find they can both be instantiated: `1` with `leaf = [Integer]` and `tree = [Integer]`, `2` with `leaf = Integer` and `tree = [Integer]`. To pick one, it checks whether the instantiation of `2` is valid for `1`. That is: is `leaf = Integer`, `tree = [Integer]` a valid instantiation for `1`? The answer is yes, because the context with the equality contraint isn't checked until later. Then, it checks for `OVERLAPPABLE`/`OVERLAPPING`/`OVERLAPS` pragmas. `OVERLAPPABLE` instances get thrown away if there is some better instance around. In this case, `1` is thrown away and only `2` remains. It is used, so `lmap id [5 :: Integer] == [5]`. The other examples also work.

In `LTTree`, you have a typo. It should be:

```
class LTTree leaf tree where ltmap :: (leaf -> leaf) -> tree -> tree
```

with `leaf`, not `a`. You've got another problem: the inferencer is very mad at you for making it do all this work:

```
> instance (Tups leaf x, ListTree x t) => LTTree leaf t where ltmap f v = lmap (tmap f) v
error: blah blah
```

Enable `ScopedTypeVariables` and `TypeApplications` to help it along:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}
instance (Tups leaf x, ListTree x t) => LTTree leaf t where ltmap f v = lmap @x @t (tmap @leaf @x f) v
```

(or just give types explicitly with `::`, but that's painful)

But the better idea is to enable `FunctionalDependencies` and start spraying them about, because they represent the very idea of type level computation: some subset of the parameters of a typeclass can uniquely determine the others. This produces the final version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances
           , FunctionalDependencies
           , GADTs
           , UndecidableInstances #-}
class ListTree leaf tree | tree -> leaf where lmap :: (leaf -> leaf) -> tree -> tree
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (leaf ~ tree) => ListTree leaf tree where lmap = id
instance ListTree leaf tree => ListTree leaf [tree] where lmap = map . lmap
-- The tree determines the leaf

class Tups leaf tree | tree -> leaf where tmap :: (leaf -> leaf) -> tree -> tree
-- Change instances to help type inference along:
instance (a ~ b) => Tups a (a, b) where tmap f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
instance (a ~ b, b ~ c) => Tups a (a, b, c) where tmap f (x, y, z) = (f x, f y, f z)
-- tmap (+2) (5 :: Integer, 3, 2) now works because the type info from 5 spreads out
-- via the equality constraints

class LTTree leaf tree | tree -> leaf where ltmap :: (leaf -> leaf) -> tree -> tree
instance (Tups leaf mid, ListTree mid tree) => LTTree leaf tree where ltmap = lmap . tmap
-- mid can be deduced from tree via ListTree's fundep
-- leaf can be deduced from mid via Tups' fundep
-- leaf can be deduced from tree
```

And it works!

```
> ltmap (+(2 :: Integer)) [[[(5, 2)]], [], [[(2, 8), (4, 5)]]]
[[[(7,4)]],[],[[(4,10),(6,7)]]]
```

Comment: Thanks as lot for this very good walkthrough! One question: why is the `(leaf ~ tree) => ListTree leaf tree` instead of `ListTree a a` necessary ? Is it so that `2` is a valid instanciation for `1`? Or some other reason?